# determine type of exception by psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

I'm using python with psycopg2. the following snippet produces some sort of error, but i'm not able to get any output, so i can't handle the error

```
cur = conn.cursor()
try:
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO mqtt.records(client, id_type, value) VALUES (%(str)s, %(int)s, %(float)s)", (topic[1], switchCase(topic[-1]), msg.payload)
except psycopg2.Error as e:
  print(e)
conn.commit()
cur.close()
```

i'm pretty sure it's some sort of typecast error, but it's not catched by the `except psycopg2.Error as e:`. if i'm using a general `except:` to catch any exceptions, it catches. but then i don't know how to get the error-message

Comment: a basic `except Exception as e:` got me the error. apparently it's not an psycopg2 exception

Answer (score 0):

using `except Exception as e:` i got the message 'arguments can't be mixed' which led me to figure that `... VALUES (%(str)s, %(int)s, %(float)s)` isnt working.

instead i had to do typecasting on the `(str(topic[1]), int(switchCase(topic[-1])), float(msg.payload))` part.

so i basicly missunderstood the docs. shame on me.